# What is a good easy to use profiler for C++ on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, profiler

I need to profile some code running C++ on Linux. Can you guys recommend some profilers?

Comment: You should add Linux and C++ tags.  You will probably get a better response and range of opinions.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux.

Comment: eg: likwid, LLTng, oprofile, valgrind, vtune, gprof, perf, gperftools, pTop

Comment: See this question on slant: https://www.slant.co/improve/topics/1005

Answer (score 39):

Use gprof.

Just compile with `-pg` flag (I think (but am not sure) you have to turn of optimizations though.) and use gprof to analyze the gmon.out file that your executable will then produce.

eg:

```
gcc -pg -o whatever whatever.c

./whatever

gprof whatever gmon.out
```

Same thing with g++ and cpp.

Comment: Profiling unoptimized code is a bit pointless, isn't it? Similarly, profiling code that has been heavily modified with -pg often misguides you into optimizing the wrong spots.

Comment: -pg is a linker option, not compiler

Answer (score 25):

[valgrind](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html) is a well-know linux profiler

Comment: thought valgrind was more for memory leak checking.. I am trying to see which functions are getting called etc

Comment: use the suite tool called "callgrind"

Comment: Valgrind is simply a framework for building dynamic tools. Although, it's become synonymous with Memcheck, a tool built on Valgrind. Callgrind is a pretty good at profiler.

Comment: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html

Answer (score 13):

I'm a fan of [Oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/). It involves installing a kernel module and has a bit of a learning curve to it, but it's fairly powerful and works very well for optimized programs/programs without debugging symbols.

[Vtune](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune/) is another very powerful profiler made by Intel. I believe the Linux version is free for Non-commercial software.

There is also the [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html) suite of tools proposed by dfa. Callgrind would probably be what you're most interested in. Cachegrind(whose featureset is a subset of Callgrind's) and Massif are interesting as well, but I have no experience with the latter.

Comment: +1 for oprofile, that is not an "easy tool"

Comment: Haha, true. I should probably not make that sound so easy :) It's certainly not as simple as "run program under it" as Vtune and Valgrind tools, but I feel you get used to it pretty quickly.

Comment: oprofile looks interesting - does it support x86_64?

Comment: VTune isn't free for any uses, unfortunately.

Answer (score 13):

Zoom from RotateRight ( http://www.rotateright.com ) is what I've been using. It has a butterfly view of functions and you can double-click any function to dive into source or asm code. Build with debugging information (-g) to see your source, but you should still build and profile *optimized* code.

Comment: Just gave this program a shot, it's really quite nice! Currently my favorite profiler on Linux; however it's worth mentioning that it requires code to be built with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` to effectively profile.

Comment: The link seems dead. Does anyone know where (or if) it can be found elsewhere?

Answer (score 5):

Google also has a nice profiler as part of the [google-perftools](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools) -- which are included in Debian / Ubuntu and possibly other distros.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [KCacheGrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/) which is a graphical frontend to [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and makes it really easy to use it.

Answer (score 2):

gprof is the standard gnu tool for profiling.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Sysprof](http://sysprof.com). You distribution most likely has it available already.

Note that all of the mentioned profilers work best if your application is compiled with frame pointers. That is, you should use -fno-omit-frame-pointer on the gcc command line.

Answer (score 0):

[This is what I use.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024)

Comment: you'll just base your judgement about the bottleneck on 10 samples you collect manually, instead of 1000 samples collected by `prof`.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: Correct, and that actually tells you what you should fix. The statistical explanation is [*here*](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262). In fact, the first mistake people make is to think that they are looking for a "bottleneck" rather than perfectly good but wasteful code ;-)

Comment: Nice read, thanks. I totally buy your point that optimizing is way easier when you see an actual function call in the debugger. And I do understand that "bottleneck" doesn't mean "good optimization target", just a potential one. Still, I think it makes sense to start with `prof` anyway: if I see that `f()` is the most problematic function statistically, I'll stop the program several times until I land in `f()` instead of just starting with a random function I stopped in first.