# Line level profiling of a C program by GNU

Tags: c, profiling, openmp, gnu

Could Someone kindly tell me how can I profile single lines or blocks of code of a program in C with GNU profiler?
I used `gprof ./a.out gmon.out` which gives me flat profile and Call graph. However, I would like to see lines that are more frequently accessed.

Thanks,

Comment: Extract those lines into their own function?  The thought "did action A of function B take too long" makes me think that action A should be its own function in the first place.

Comment: This seems to be an answer though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263573/is-there-a-profiler-for-c-gcc-to-profile-code-lines-separately?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

This is probably one of those things that you just don't know the term you should've googled, so I'll answer it:

The term you are looking for is "annotation"-you want to annotate the source and see the line by line hits in the code.

Calling gprof with the `-A` flag will dump out the samples on each line that were caught.

See Also:

https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/Annotated-Source.html

Comment: But it won't give you inclusive percent by line. (If a line is a big slow function call, it won't see it.) Nor does it give you wall-clock time. (It's blind to I/O.)

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-Gcov.html :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll post this answer so if some newbie like me searched for it can find it faster :)
 here are the steps: [source](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-Gcov.html)

1. `gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage fourcefile.c`
   (At the end of compilation files *.gcno will be produced)
2. Run the executable.
3. Run gcov: `gcov sourcefile.c`
   (At the end of running, a file (*.gcov) will be produced which contains which contains all the required info)