# How to do time profiling of a C program in HP-UX?

Tags: performance, gcc, profiling, hp-ux

I want to do a time-based profiling of an application written in C on HP-UX. I want to see which function is taking maximum amount of time, slowing down the operational duration. Is there a way to do it? I know I can use *-p* option in Linux and generate *mon.out* and then use *prof* command to generate the profile. But, I don't think that's the correct compiler option on HP-UX.

I would love to get some help here. I did find one similar answer here:
[Is there a profiler for C (gcc) to profile code lines separately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263573/is-there-a-profiler-for-c-gcc-to-profile-code-lines-separately?rq=1)

However, I did not quite extract the thing I need, especially for HP-UX fro this post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771

Answer (score 0):

For hp-ux/ia64, you should be able to use [Caliper](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c02919899) (bundled with the OS)

```
caliper fprof -o fprof.out a.out
```

For hp-ux/parisc it used to be `prospect` or `gprof`, I can't find sources right now.