# memory profiling tool for linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, embedded-linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good easy to use profiler for C++ on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168766/what-is-a-good-easy-to-use-profiler-for-c-on-linux)

Is there some opensource memory profiling tools for embedded linux? I need to know the memory cost status of a certain program , so I want this tool have some features such as  calculate how much memory used with malloc, how much stack/heap used in pthreads, and show the shared library's memory usage. is there some tools can qualify.
thanks.

Comment: Seriously, this hasn't been asked earlier here?

Answer (score 5):

Everyone uses [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) for this.

Comment: valgrind's memory profiler is limited to 32GByte (it is quite an art to implement such a limit!)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the memory profiling debugging tools I have used as some point of time so far :

1. Valgrind
2. Intel's VTune

3 . IBM Rational Purify